# Assets 2.1.2 not showing files on front-end

Tags: pixelandtonic, assets, bug

I'm doing some local dev with Assets 2.1.2 and trying to get it to output a folders and file structure.

However, I can get the folders to display but no files. Even the tags that are meant to output the count of files/folders don't show there are files there.

The files display perfectly well within Assets in the Control Panel

This is the code I'm using to test.

```
<ul>
{exp:assets:folders}
    <li>{folder_name}</a>
        <p>Total subfolders: {total_subfolders}</p>
        {if total_subfolders}
            <ul>
                {subfolders}
            </ul>
        {/if}
        <ul>
            {exp:assets:files}
                    <li>
                        <p>Total files: {total_files}<br>
                        <a href="{url}">{if title != ""}{title}{if:else}{filename}{/if} ({size})</a></li>
                        {if no_results}<p>No files</p>{/if}
            {/exp:assets:files}
        </ul>
    </li>
{/exp:assets:folders}
</ul>
```

The resulting output looks like this

```
Content images
Total subfolders: 0

Member files
Total subfolders: 0

News images
Total subfolders: 0

Provider Logos
Total subfolders: 0

Projects
Total subfolders: 11

    Committee
    Total subfolders: 10

        Meetings
        Total subfolders: 4

            2012-12-05 Berlin
            Total subfolders: 1

                Presentations
                Total subfolders: 0

            2013-01-28 Paris
            Total subfolders: 0

            2013-04-21 London
            Total subfolders: 0

       Project Groups
       Total subfolders: 4

           PG1
           Total subfolders: 0

           PG2
           Total subfolders: 0

           PG3
           Total subfolders: 0

           PG4
           Total subfolders: 0

Slider images
Total subfolders: 0
```

There are a number of files in the 2012-12-05 Berlin directory (as well as the top level directories) that just don't show up.

Furthermore adding the folder_id, parent_folder or folder parameters doesn't have any effect on what is output. The list always starts from the top most directory.

I've tried setting it to output from {filedir_6} (which is the Projects directory) but the output is just as above.

So... but in Assets 2.1.2 or am I missing something?

Comment: Are your file paths relative or err....the other kind?

Comment: Hey foamcow - I have a few bug reports in around this not working.  I think that you may be running into those.  I'll keep you updated on that progress.

Comment: John, the paths are in the form '/path/from/server/root/to/directory'

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. Any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the long wait - we've isolated the bug and fixed it - the fix will be included in the next release.

For a hot-fix, open the third_party/assets/libraries/assets_lib file, locate the get_files_in_folder method and add this at the very beginning of this method:

```
if (is_array($file_ids))
{
  $file_ids = array_filter($file_ids);
}
```

That should fix your thing!

Comment: I tried the patch and it seemed to sort of work. Now I've updated to the new version 2.1.3 and I'm finding that files are displayed but I cannot get the parent_folder parameter to work. It just seems to be ignored.